# ThreeJS – smooth scaling object while mouseover

Tags: object, three.js, scale, onmouseover

another ThreeJS question: 
How can I make a hovered (intersected) object scale smooth to a defined size? My current code is

`INTERSECTED.scale.x *= 1.5;
 INTERSECTED.scale.y *= 1.5;`

but this only works like on/off.

**Edit: My Solution (with tweenJS)**

While mouseOver I scale up the element to 200% :

```
function scaleUp(){
    new TWEEN.Tween( INTERSECTED.scale ).to( {
       x: 2,
       y: 2 
    }, 350 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.EaseOut).start();
}
```

While mouseOut I scale down the element to 100% :

```
function scaleDown(){
    new TWEEN.Tween( INTERSECTED.scale ).to( {
       x: 1,
       y: 1 
    }, 350 ).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.EaseOut).start();
}
```

Finally I call the functions in the mouse function.

```
if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED)
   scaleUp();
else
   scaleDown();
```

That's all. Very useful for UIs I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tween library (found in three.js/examples/js/libs/tween.min.js) you can animate the scale like so:

```
function setupObjectScaleAnimation( object, source, target, duration, delay, easing )
{
    var l_delay = ( delay !== undefined ) ? delay : 0;
    var l_easing = ( easing !== undefined ) ? easing : TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None;

    new TWEEN.Tween( source )
        .to( target, duration )
        .delay( l_delay )
        .easing( l_easing )
        .onUpdate( function() { object.scale.copy( source ); } )
        .start();
}

and then call it like so:

setupObjectScaleAnimation( INTERSECTED,
    { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 2, z: 2 },
    2000, 500, TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None );
```

Or if you want to use the render loop:

```
clock = new THREE.Clock();
time = clock.getElapsedTime();

INSPECTED.scale.x = time / 1000;
INSPECTED.scale.y = time / 1000;
```

You can change the divisor based on how fast or slow you want the animation to happen.

Comment: Is there a way without the tween lib? I'd like to use the render loop instead of extra stuff

Comment: Thanks for the tips @gaitat ! Unfortunately couldn't make it without tweenJS but I updated my post with my solution.